# Github push error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit

Tags: git, github

I'm having issues pushing a new git changeset to the github repository.
First I cloned my local changes with a depth of 1 to remove the history as:

```
git clone --depth 1 file:///Users/kunal<path to project>
```

Then I ran a git init remote add and push as inside of the directory I cloned:

```
> git init  
> git remote add origin https://github.com/kp27/pymovie2.git 

> git push -u origin master
```

I see the files upload, but then I get:

```
Counting objects: 7110, done.

Delta compression using up to 8 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (3785/3785), done.

Writing objects: 100% (7110/7110), 7.60 MiB | 247 KiB/s, done.

Total 7110 (delta 2283), reused 7110 (delta 2283)

error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? My first guess is the depth of 1 is causing it, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal test repo that causes the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I deleted contents of /.git/ and tried again - it worked. **Be careful doing this.**

Story:
I had similar problem related to some error in renaming folders, which persisted even after deletion and (re-)cloning

(on mac os x):
I **first copied my files to a safe directory** on computer, then
navigated into /.git/ and deleted all contents (cmd-shift-g ".git" in Finder)
and finally deleted /.git/ in terminal

then was able to commit and push

Answer (score 4):

You need to contact github for this, it's something on the receiving end.

You could also clone the github repository and instead of cloning your local files, just copy them over and add them.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What do you mean, by on the receiving end?

Comment: Github, there seems to be a problem on their side.

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened, when I tried to push the new files which are not added to the index. try adding the files to index using Team-> Add To Index in eclipse thru EGit plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Varun. The question isn't related to EGit, the error might have a completetly different reason. Further, the error is probably related to the fact that the TO was trying to pushing a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case, *not gitgub*, but for another repo git. If you can, check if the **user** who is **logged** in with git has **permission to write** to these directories, and if not then in **chmod** and continue to know you already know...

Comment: I had the same error and checking permission should be the first thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clone it again, just run this command in git repo `git repack remote/origin/master`
For more details check out this http://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/2009/10/08/unpacker-error-when-pushing-git/

Comment: Not solving the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

In case of repack didn't help pull with rebase can help:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when using GitHub Enterprise. Push worked until it suddenly didn't work.

I deleted the repo then re-created it, then this issue was gone. (Thankfully it was a very trivial repo)

Indeed, this seems to be GitHub's platform's problem. If it is not possible to delete and re-create the repo, I guess the only option is to contact support.